# Add boolean to split log

Tags: powershell

I like to edit a little Parameter more to it. Now it is splitting the File every $linesperfile but I want to add in the params $split wich should be a boolean. it should split it every $linesperfile or leave in in only one file .. I tried it allready but everytime it`s ending in a permanent loop.

**call.ps1**

```
D:\powershell.ps1 -filename "D:\Test\WindowsUpdate.log" -rootName "D:\backup-logs\Apache2_Lognummer_" -ext ".log" -linesperFile 10000 -path "D:\backup-logs\" -split "true"
```

**powershell.ps1**

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [string]$filename,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [string]$rootName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
    [string]$ext,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]
    [string]$linesperFile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=4)]
    [string]$path,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=5)]
    [string]$split
)

############################## Parameter ##############################

$sw = new-object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$sw.Start() # Timer startet


$DateNow = ((Get-date).Day).ToString()+"-"+`
           ((Get-date).Month).ToString()+"-"+`
           ((Get-date).Year).ToString()+"-"+`
           ((Get-date).Hour).ToString()+"-"+`
           ((Get-date).Minute).ToString()+"-"+`
           ((Get-date).Second).ToString()+".log" # Ermittelt das aktuelle Datum (Deutscher Timestamp Tag-Monat-Jahr-Stunde-Minute-Sekunde !)
$filecount = 1 # Namenszähler
$reader = $null

############################ Skript Start #############################

try{
    $reader = [io.file]::OpenText($filename)
    try{
        "Creating file number $filecount"
        $writer= [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory("$path\$DateNow")
        $writer = [io.file]::CreateText("{0}{1}_{2}" -f ($rootName,$filecount.ToString("0000"),$DateNow,$ext))
        $linecount = 0
        $filecount++

        while($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
            "Reading $linesperFile"
            while( ($linecount -lt $linesperFile) -and ($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true)){
                $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine());
                $linecount++
            }

            if($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
                "Closing file"
                $writer.Dispose();

                "Creating file number $filecount"
                $writer= [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory("$path\$DateNow") 
                $writer = [io.file]::CreateText("{0}{1}_{2}" -f ($rootName,$filecount.ToString("0000"),$DateNow,$ext))
                $filecount++
                $linecount = 0
            }
        }
    } finally {
        $writer.Dispose();
    }
} finally {
    $reader.Dispose();
}

############################ Logfile verschieben ############################

$mostRecentSubDir = Get-ChildItem $path\ | Where-Object { $_.psiscontainer } | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1
Robocopy $path $path\$mostRecentSubDir *.log /move

#Remove-Item $path | Where-Object name -like "*.log"

####################### Veraltete Verzeichnisse und Logdateien löschen/leeren #######################

$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60) # Anzahl Tage bis Löschung

# Lösche Dateien älter als $limit.
 Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force

# Löscht leere Verzeichnisse -- > Uncomment 
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

 Clear-Content $filename # Löscht alten Inhalt der .Logfile ($filename siehe oben) nachdem diese gebackupt wurde.

#####################################################################

$sw.Stop() # Timer stops

Write-Host "Backup complete in " $sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds "seconds" # Ausgabe des Timers über die Kommandozeile


############################ Skrict End ############################
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have all of your variables declared as `[string]`.  Declare `$linesperfile` as an `[int]`:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]
[int]$linesperFile,
```

I also recommend changing your `$split` variable to a `[Switch]` type.

Comment: ok, I added it to the Parameters. Thanks for that. - Now I like to edit the loop that he also checks the $split parameter that when it`s false he doesn`t start to split it so it all in one logfile. when it`s true he should split it by the number given at the $linesperfile parameter.

Comment: can someone help me out with this issue ?